# text-overflow "string" invalid property value Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

Do anyone know why all default values for text-overflow work in google Chrome except from the "string" value?

if you want to check it you can open mozilla and chrome with this link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/

then you can go to the first "codepen" box which shows the implementation and inspect the performance when `text-overflow: "---"` in both browsers.

In mozilla firefox 45.0 works, but in chrome 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) doesn't.. and the error is invalid property value...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply, it is not supported by Chrome.

See browser compatibility:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow